# Trying to use Font as WCF service parameter

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which requires font data. So I created my own class which has a member of the System.Drawing.Font type. I checked, the Font class is marked as serializable. When I try to call the method, passing in my object, I get the following error:

> {"Type 'System.Drawing.FontStyle' with data contract name
>   'FontStyle:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing' is
>   not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer."}

Note it's complaining about FontStyle, which is actually a property of the Font class. FontStyle is a simple flags enum, which I'm not even setting (but it has a default value I suppose).

So is it possible / best practise to just reuse the Font class for this, or do I need to implement it differently?

Answer (score 1):

The exception just means that when the serializer examines the classes you're serializing, it can't figure out that it needs to include the FontStyle enum. Try marking your class (the one with a Font property) with the [KnownType(typeof(System.Drawing.FontStyle))] attribute.

Also, take a look at your generated client and make sure the KnownType attribute makes it in there. There are some issues with svcutil where it sometimes leaves out known types when the type isn't used in the top level parameter class.

Comment: I tried adding the KnownType to the datacontract class, that didn't make a difference. As for the client code, it's a bit more complicated because this is a SharePoint Service Application. There is no client code as such; because SharePoint works with it's own proxy classes which are then routed via loadbalancers and stuff like that.